# linux status/info screen for appliance

Tags: linux

I've been messing around with CentOS5 recently.  I've made a piece of software that runs when the server boots and does what I need it to do.  Since the software is network/web related, I don't need interactive login to the local terminal of the server.

I want to setup an "info" screen on the local terminal that shows you the current ip address of the server as well as other stats.  I don't want you to have to log in to the local terminal to see the info screen.  I just want it to be displayed on the local VGA output once the server is booted.

I'm talking about something like this screen:

[image: screen shot of vmware vcenter server appliance startup screen with ip addresses]

Any thoughts?  I'm not sure I understand the flow of the local terminal.  How one would get it to switch from showing the login prompt to something like this?  Are their any open source software projects that already do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the getty that runs on the the first terminal with an application which does what you have in the screenshot. You'll need a solid understanding of how something like getty works and the security implications of writing something to replace it with. I would suggest by virtue of the fact that you're asking this question, that you are likely unequipped to solve the problem without some manner of 3rd party intervention. Alternatively, if security is not a serious consideration, you could opt for an auto-login solution and an application that runs after or instead of the user's shell.

Edit: Looking at the information you need to display, perhaps /etc/issue will suffice.

Comment: /etc/issue is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!